# How can I prevent a web page that includes the HTML5 manifest attribute from being included in the application cache?

Tags: html

This page, http://appcachefacts.info/, says the HTML5 application cache can be "used online to dramatically decrease load times.".

How can I prevent a web page that includes the html manifest attribute from being included in the application cache (because some contents are dynamically created on the server)?

I am working with an embedded web server. I prefer a simple (JavaScript, HTML) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the page which references the manifest is always included in the Application Cache.  Try creating a dummy static page with the manifest reference and loading it in an `iframe`.

Comment: The iframe approach works but leads to a problem with my Style.css file. The file is listed in the manifest, and in the original page. If I keep the css file in the original page, it is requested from the server. If I remove it from the original page, it is not requested from the server but I lose my styles. Do I have something setup wrong?

Comment: @Mr.Wonderful As long as you put a decent [expires header](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/rules.html#expires) on your static content it shouldn't ever get requested more than once.  If that doesn't help you should probably ask another question specifically about your Style.css issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the embedded web server I am using does not support the use of expires headers (which prompted me to look for other ways to cache). But thank for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the web page to the NETWORK section of the cache manifest.

> NETWORK - Files listed under this header require a connection to the
>   server, and will never be cached

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_app_cache.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work, the page which references the manifest is always cached.